# Typescript doesn't recognize d.ts modules

Tags: typescript

Trying to use typescript with Koa.

`koa-respond` and `@koa/cors` do not have `@types` packages so I added a file `ambient-types.d.ts` in my src with these declarations

```
declare module 'koa-respond'
declare module '@koa/cors'
```

However I still get these errors from ts

```
Try `npm install @types/koa__cors` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'koa__cors';`
src/server.ts(7,26): error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'koa-respond'. '/home/hayk/projects/learning/koa/koala/backend/node_modules/koa-respond/lib/koa-respond.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/koa-respond` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'koa-respond';`
```

This is my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2017",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "sourceMap": true
},
"include": [
    "./src/**/*"
]
}
```

And I run like this `nodemon --watch 'src/**/*' -e ts,tsx --exec 'ts-node' ./index.ts`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to my testing, you need to specify the `--files` option to `ts-node` to force it to load all the files matching the `include` setting in your `tsconfig.json`, otherwise `ambient-types.d.ts` never gets loaded.

```
nodemon --watch 'src/**/*' -e ts,tsx --exec 'ts-node --files' ./index.ts
```

Answer (score -2):

you might need to specify `typeRoots` directory in tsconfig.json
in that directory, I usually create subdirectories with same names as the modules I want to writing typings for
each directory would have a `index.d.ts` file, with `declare module ...... { ... }` stuff in it

```
/ 
/tsconfig.json
/typings
/typings/my-module/index.d.ts
```